# Write and execute a C or C++ program that creates an infinite number of processes.

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, unix, process

I have a C++ program that creates process threads in LINUX. How can I modify this code to create an infinite amount of processes? I have the count currently set to 5.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

using namespace std;

#define THREAD_COUNT     5

void *PrintPhrase(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   cout << "THis Is A Great Day Thread ID, " << tid << endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
   pthread_t threads[THREAD_COUNT];
   int rc;
   uintptr_t i;
   for( i=0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++ ){
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, 
                          PrintPhrase, (void *)i);

      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

  pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Comment: [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)?

Comment: Threads aren't processes, there are significant differences.

Comment: So you want to create a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)? That's going to crash your machine so hard. If you can't change 5 to a much larger number on your own I'm not sure what we can do to help.

Comment: Your ulimits might prevent you from doing so. Try clone() as well

Comment: You can't create an infinite number.  It would take too long.

Comment: There is a limit of threads or processes that can be created (and running) before they become pointless.  At this limit, the OS spends more time managing the threads (processes) than actually executing the processes.  If this doesn't happen, then the first process may finish before the last process is created and run.  Remember, unless you can have the OS assign one process per CPU (core), it will have to run a process for a time, then swap it out with another process (or if the process blocks, like waiting for I/O).

Comment: no i will not help you write malicious code.

Answer (score 0):

For *infinite*, I suggest these changes:

Replace `for` loop with `while (true)`.

Replace:

```
pthread_t threads[THREAD_COUNT];
```

with:

```
std::vector<pthread_t> threads;
```

Your loop would look like:

```
   while (true)
   {
      pthread temp;
      rc = pthread_create(&temp, NULL, 
                          PrintPhrase, (void *)i);
      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      threads.push_back(temp);
   }
```